# Python Sparse matrix demensions mismatch scipy.sparse.coo_matrix

Tags: python, scipy

```
import scipy.sparse
XTrain_Sparse=scipy.sparse.coo_matrix((x3, (x1,x2)))
print('Shape of Sparse X: '+ str(XTrain_Sparse.shape))
```

Why am I getting output as

> "Shape of Sparse X: (4001, 51950)"

if `max(x1) = 4000` and `max(x2) = 51949`.

Shouldn't my sparse matrix shape be `(4000, 51949)`?

Comment: Why should the shape be (4000, 51949)?  You didn't specify a shape, so it deduced the same from your inidices.

Answer (score 0):

From the [scipy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html)

```
coo_matrix((data, (i, j)), [shape=(M, N)])
   to construct from three arrays:

     data[:] the entries of the matrix, in any order
     i[:] the row indices of the matrix entries
     j[:] the column indices of the matrix entries
```

So the integers in `x1` and `x2` you are passing are indices of the matrix.  If the max indices are `4000` and `51949` on on a zero-based index, then the dimensions will be `(4001, 51950)`.

Comment: Why would the dimension would change? You didn't supply an explanation and merely referenced to the documentation. Can you elaborate? because from what I know it suppose to be  M*N shape and not M+1 * N shape

Comment: @Green, the OP did not specify (M,N) so `coo` deduced the shape from the indices (one more than the max in both dimensions - consistent with normal Python practice).

Comment: @Green If x1, x2 = [0], then the shape will be (1,1)